# Is it possible to choose the test class by passing the parameter with @parameters annotations?

Tags: java, selenium

I got two products to be tested by the Selenium code. As their versions are slightly different, I think having two Selenium codes for each product is better. So I created a Java that has a switch block to determine which version of Selenium Java code will run.

```
public class TestInit {

    @Parameters("appver")
    @Test
    void test(String version) {
        System.out.println("App version: " + version);
        switch (version) {
            case "8.00.25":
                TestRun1 test1 = new TestRun1();
                break;
            case "8.00.35":
                TestRun2 test2 = new TestRun2();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("default version will be running");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

My textNG.xml passes parameters to the above Java class and one of the parameters is `appver`. However, I don't know how to run my code based on this parameter to run `TestRun1` class. The variable `appver` receives the value from `testNG.xml` properly.

```
public class TestRun1 {

    @Test
    void test1(){
        System.out.println("This is test run in Testrun1");
    }
}
```

Additionally, how do you manage to handle different test cases for different versions? Do you create new Java and then override test cases on it?

Comment: never ever do that! the purpose of tests is to check either positive or negative scenarios, there is no place for branches.

Comment: But I want to. Understood the purpose, but what would be the best practice for the case? Didn't mention on the OP, I am using Maven project and command for test maven command would be `test -DsuiteXmlFile=testngxml_test/testrun.xml -DtestID=$BUILD_ID -Dbrowser=firefox -Dapp.ver=8.00.35 -Dtest.ver=test` That's why I asked.

Comment: you just need two different versions of test suite for two different versions of application